# Convert shapefile data to NMEA - simulate NMEA positions from shape data

Tags: shapefile, nmea, simulation

To generate waypoints to be read by the agricultural GNSS-RTK-steering system CEREA, I am looking for a way to simulate NMEA strings of a GNSS receiver by clicking the edges of the boundaries of polygon shapefiles within QGIS.

Is there a way to do that edge by edge of the polygon? The data should be exported via TCP/IP to be read by the navigation system as if the data where actual position data of a GNSS receiver using NMEA strings $GNRMC / $GPRMC and $GNGGA / $GPGGA.

If there is no way within QGIS, a workaround could be a program, that sends NMEA data from coordinates that I copy and paste from a CSV file of the shape data.

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I have a solution:

I found a NMEA Generator that can be fed with coordinates in a CSV file that I created with QGIS from the shapefiles before. Using a port splitting tool I can simulate NMEA data on one computer, watch them via TCP in QGIS on the same computer and send them via a serial bridge to the computer of the steering system, which reads them in the same way as real GNSS receiver data.

Thus I can create guidinglines and boundaries, that I can use for steering my machines in the fields later.